# Trying to hide a label in tkinter after pressed a button

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tkinter

I'm trying to hide some labels in my code of tkinter.
I'm loading images and then I apply some pre-processing techinque by the moment.

The case is, i have three labels which were added to the widget called "miframe" and all those are in the same coordinates:

```
labelmaduro = Label(miframe, image=ruta_maduro).place(x=25, y=60)
labelpinton = Label(miframe, image=ruta_pinton).place(x=25, y=60)
labelverde = Label(miframe, image=ruta_verde).place(x=25, y=60)
```

All the labels are added to frame one over another, I'm finding a way of hide all those labels after push the button "Select Image" and when I pushed the button calle "Predict" show i.g the "labelmature".
I should hide all those labels when the program has already started, but by the moment i can't do that,
I tryed used `label1.lower()`  `place_forget()`to hide those labels and to show it, I tryed `mylabel.pack()`

```
from tkinter import * 
import cv2
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import numpy as np


def select_image():
    # grab a reference to the image panels
    global panelA, panelB
    # open a file chooser dialog and allow the user to select an input
    # image
    #ocultar clase predecida anteriormente:

    path = fd.askopenfilename()

        # ensure a file path was selected
    if len(path) > 0:
        # load the image from disk, convert it to grayscale, and detect
        # edges in it
        image = cv2.imread(path)
        median = cv2.medianBlur(image, 9)
        #Resize
        #BGT TO RGB
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        median = cv2.cvtColor(median, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        dim = (340, 257)
        original = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        median = cv2.resize(median, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

        # Convertir imagenes al formato PIL
        original = Image.fromarray(original)
        median = Image.fromarray(median)

        #Pass to ImageTk format
        original = ImageTk.PhotoImage(original)
        median = ImageTk.PhotoImage(median)

        #if the panels are none
        if panelA is None or panelB is None:
            #El primer panel guarda la primera imagen
            panelA = Label(image=original)
            panelA.image = original
            panelA
            panelA.pack(side="left", padx=10, pady=10)

            #the second panel show the pre-processed image
            panelB = Label(image=median)
            panelB.image = median
            panelB.pack(side="right", padx=10, pady=10)

            hideLabels()
        #in other cases update the panels
        else:
            # update the pannels
            panelA.configure(image=original)
            panelB.configure(image=median)
            panelA.image = original
            panelB.image = median

            hideLabels()

def hideGreen():
    labelverde.place_forget()

def hideLabels():
    hideGreen()

def showMature():
    labelmaduro.pack() #show label after push Predict Button

#Initialize the main window
root = Tk()
root.configure(background='black')
root.title("Opencv test")
panelA = None
panelB = None

#Frame which contains the labels
miframe = Frame(bg="#0F2D80", width="200", height="200")

ruta_maduro = PhotoImage(file="maduro.png")
ruta_pinton = PhotoImage(file="pinton.png")
ruta_verde = PhotoImage(file="verde.png")

#Create labels to show and hidde according to the prediction
labelmaduro = Label(miframe, image=ruta_maduro).place(x=25, y=60)
labelpinton = Label(miframe, image=ruta_pinton).place(x=25, y=60)
labelverde = Label(miframe, image=ruta_verde).place(x=25, y=60)


#add frame to root
miframe.pack(side="right", anchor="n", padx=10)

#User buttons
btn2 = Button(root, text="Predict Button", command=showMature)
btn2.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes", padx="10", pady="10")

btn = Button(root, text="Select Image", command=select_image)
btn.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes", padx="10", pady="10")

root.resizable(0,0)
# kick off the GUI
root.mainloop()
```

I want to hide all those labels and show only one of them after pressing the "predict" button, but when the program has already started all those labels should be hided, therefore i should only show one label according the predicted class.
[image: program image which starts with the label green/verde over all the labels]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **None** values in all of those 3 Labels, that is because you're assigning Label's method `place(..)` return value to the objects of those Labels, as `place` returns `None` *(same for pack or grid)*.

Always do,

```
labelmaduro = Label(miframe, image=ruta_maduro)
labelmaduro.place(x=25, y=60)
```

Or if you want no object for a `Label` and just want to assign it without modifying it further in your code then you can use it like this.

```
Label(miframe, image=ruta_maduro).place(x=25, y=60)
```

---

**Now for hiding labels.**

You don't need three labels to *show / hide* to achieve that kind of functionality. It can be done by modifying the *image* of the existing `Label`  so in that case you just need one `Label` and configure it's *image* resource to different one depending on your need like so...

```
img_label.config(image=ruta_pinton)
```

Here is an example of changing images of a single `Label` from different `Buttons`.

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()

ruta_maduro = PhotoImage(file="maduro.png")
ruta_pinton = PhotoImage(file="pinton.png")
ruta_verde = PhotoImage(file="verde.png")

img_label = Label(root)
img_label.pack()

Button(root, text='maduro', command=
    lambda: img_label.config(image=ruta_maduro)).pack()
Button(root, text='maduro', command=
    lambda: img_label.config(image=ruta_pinton)).pack()
Button(root, text='maduro', command=
    lambda: img_label.config(image=ruta_verde)).pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks so much Saad, now i can fix this.. I was putting those labels in a frame.. also I going to try to improve the design of the interface and finally implement the svm classifier.